# Fullcalendar Display 24 hour time as 24:00 instead of 00:00

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar

Fullcalendar how to change event end time 00:00 to 24:00 
currently its automatic displaying 24:00 as 00:00 .

```
     defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
      axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
      selectOverlap: true,
      allDaySlot: false,
      selectHelper: true,
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
      slotLabelFormat: 'HH:mm',
      slotDuration: '1:00',
      snapDuration: '0:15',
      columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd-D',
      titleFormat: 'MMMM D , YYYY',
      windowResizeDelay: 0,
      eventLongPressDelay: 0,
      longPressDelay: 0,
      displayEventEnd: true,
      minTime: '00:00:00',
      maxTime: '24:00:00',
```

[image]

Comment: try by set max time as 23:59:59 instead of 24:00:00

Comment: i tried .. but the result is same

Comment: I assume you're referring to the time display at the bottom of each event? If so please show what code you used to create that time display. I guess you used some custom CSS and/or JavaScript to do that? And also to get it to show "24:00" at the bottom of the time grid. So please show all that code, because it's not possible to suggest fixes to code we cannot see. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Refer the following [Link](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/5303).

Just change your locale to `'en-GB'`. Problem solved.